# Capturar evento retroceder y avanzar navegación en Angular

Tags: angular

A ver chicxs, os traigo un reto que escapa totalmente de mi lógica y no sé ni cómo implementar, cabe decir que no sé mucho frontEnd, pero no me queda otra, el proyecto es en solitario.

Tengo mi API (node) que devuelve un json con todos los elementos que se encuentran en un directorio concreto (carpetas o archivos). Quiero recorrer ese JSON y mostrar cada índice en el front, hasta ahí fantástico, funciona perfectamente.

La cosa es, si pulso en una carpeta y navego hasta ella (mismo proceso que antes), al pulsar el botón de retroceso, me lleva a la página anterior, no al directorio anterior en la ruta.

Tengo preparado un sistema de breadcrumbs para saber cuál era el directorio anterior y recomponer la ruta que tengo que solicitar a la API, pero no puedo continuar con este problema.
En escritorio funciona muy bien (tengo un botón exclusivamente para retroceder), pero cuando navego por el sistema de archivos desde un teléfono me vuelvo loco, pulso el botón atrás de la barra de navegación por inercia (Android).

La idea es que en vez de retroceder una página, retroceda un directorio, ¿hay alguna forma de capturar el evento, anular el funcionamiento por defecto y usarlo a mi manera? No necesito código, solo que alguien me diga por dónde tirar aproximadamente, yo me las apaño como sea.

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Para entender mejor la idea y poder mejorar lo que ya tienes implementado. Igual, si tu ruta de URL coincide con tu ruta de directorios, puedes usar la sintaxis relativa con `..` para subir un directorio arriba: `this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route });` utilizando `ActivatedRoute` y `Router`

Comment: No puedo publicar ningún ejemplo porque no sé ni por dónde empezar, no tengo nada hecho sobre ese tema. Respecto a lo la URL, las peticiones se hacen mediante POST para que no se vea en el historial, por lo tanto es "invisible", no me interesa que un usuario deje rastro de cómo es su estructura de archivos, así que (hasta donde mi lógica alcanza), el router de Angular lo tengo que anular de alguna forma para que no responda a dicho evento